# Persist the "copy as path" Explorer context menu option

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer

I am a frequent user of the `[Shift]` + `[RightMouse]` --> `"Copy as Path"` feature in Windows Explorer. For those of you who may be unfamiliar with this, it's an easy way to copy a fully qualified path to a filesystem location, which is useful in many scenarios (eg. plugging in a path to upload a file via a web browser).

Since I use the option so frequently, I'm wondering if there is a way to persist this option in the Windows Explorer context menu, so that I do not have to press `[Shift]` each time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [solution](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=168&t=Copy_File_Path_and_Name_using_Windows_Explorer_Context_Menu_Extensions).  I havent tried it, but it looks legitimate.

From the website/author:

> When the utilities are installed properly, Windows Explorer will get
>   four new context menu options. Two of the menu options will be
>   available for files and the other two will be for folders. These
>   options will allow you to copy the path or the name of the file or
>   folder that you have right-clicked.